# python dictionary to file

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

At the moment I'm trying to write a dictionary to a file (in the same way the file is read). I thought using pandas was a good idea (since I also use it for reading of the same file), but that doesn't do what I want.

My data looks someting like this:

```
dict = {'x': np.array([1,2,3,4,5,etc.]), 'h': np.array([4,5,6,7,8,etc.])}
```

I want this data to be written to a file in the following format (since I retrieve it in this way as well):

```
x          h
1          4
2          5
3          6
4          7
5          8
etc.       etc.
```

I tried this, which works, but not in the way I want it:

```
a = pd.Series(dict)
a.to_csv(filename, sep='\t')
```

Any advice on how to do this (or is it easier to write it using just python?)

Comment: "I tried this, which works, but not in the way I want it:" What is happening instead?

Comment: @MrE I've just tried it, it writes a file with two lines, `h [4 5 6 7 8]` and `x [1 2 3 4 5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple series of data, the right data structure for you in Pandas is the [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe). Having a look at the [options for writing CSV files](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-store-in-csv), I see that for your desired output, I also have to pass the argument `index=False` (otherwise it would write the row numbers in the first column).

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'x': np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), 'h': np.array([4,5,6,7,8])}

a = pd.DataFrame(d)
a.to_csv("testfile.txt", sep="\t", index=False)
```

This code produces the following text file:

```
h   x
4   1
5   2
6   3
7   4
8   5
```

PS: Don't create a variable named `dict`. It'll overwrite the type.